# Find in Files where 28th line does not start with value

Tags: notepad++

I have about 400 files that I want to find if any have line 28 that does not start with "Entry" can I do this?  If so how?  My understanding is I'd have to use regex?

Comment: Regex won't be helpful for that task, but another utility such as `awk` could.

Answer (score 1):

It might be done with a Regexp:

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog, in the Find in Files Tab enter:
- **Find What:** `\A(.*\R){27}(?!Entry)`
- **Replace With:** `` (keep Field empty)
- Fill  `Filters` and `Directory` and the checkboxes on the right as required
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Find All

**Explanation of the RegExp:**

- `\A` matches at the start of the buffer, e.g. the file
- `(.*\R){27}` matches the next 27 lines:

  - `\R` matches the newline
  - `.*` zero or more arbitrary characters before
- `(?!Entry)` is a negative lookahead, it matches when the 27th. newline is *not* followed by the string `Entry`